# Rails logout redirecting not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image]

My routes:

```
destroy_client_contact_session DELETE /client_contacts/sign_out(.:format)                                                          sessions#destroy
```

Getting `GET` call `No routes` error.

I've tried adding `method="delete"` too. Still the same error.

Comment: Is `rails-ujs` required in your application.js? like:`//= require rails-ujs`

Comment: Does the route show when u do "rake routes"?

Comment: Yes it showed when I ran rake routes. That is from where I copied it

Comment: I removed the id = "client-contact-logout" part, added method="delete" along with data-method="delete" and it is working. I don't know why.

That id was using for segment tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below rails code for logout:

```
<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_client_contact_session_path, method: :delete, class: "navbar-avatar") %>
```

OR

## config/initializers/devise.rb

change

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

to

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Comment: +1

Can you also help me with why after removing ID, it is working.Because we need to track this into segment Analytics

<div class="pull-right"><a href="/client_contacts/sign_out" data-method="delete" method="delete" class="cp_header_link" ><i class="sl-logout"></i> "logout"</a></div>

Comment: @vishnuvardhan I think the issue is with `method="delete"` its abent initially.

Comment: @vishnuvardhan Have you run my rails code and test it. Vote and accept my answer if it helps you. Thanks